# Java version of WPF ItemsConrtol

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on porting a WPF application to Java.swing and while most of the project is complete I have run into one obstacle I'm not sure how to handle with my relatively limited knowledge of swing.
  There is a ItemsControl elements that I need to replace.  I'm pretty sure I can mimic the logic of adding/removing controls as the data set changes I'm just stuck as to what kind of container would work best and how to manage what controls are listed.  The controls need to be in a vertical layout like a list with new controls added to the bottom.

Update #1

Ok, I have a box layout that lists the components vertically but if the list is not full it streatches them vertically to fill the entire list space.

```
  public SearchPanel() {
    initComponents();
    ComponentList.add(new Allocater());// add allocater for testing.
    ComponentList.add(new Allocater());// add allocater for testing.
    ComponentList.add(new Allocater());// add allocater for testing.
  }

  private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
  jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
  ComponentList = new javax.swing.JPanel();
  private javax.swing.JPanel ComponentList;

  private void initComponents() {
    //.....
    ComponentList.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(ComponentList, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(ComponentList);
    //......
    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
      jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 408, Short.MAX_VALUE)
      .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
      .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
      jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 126, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    //......
  }
```

Comment: I've added an example with box layout and scroll panes that does not fill the entire space. See the answer below.

Comment: Note: Swing is about the same level as .NET Windows Forms. If you're looking for a Java "equivalent" of WPF then have a look at JavaFX.

Comment: Not an equivalent to WPF, just the controls.  I actually kinda hate WPF!  I'm just stuck porting this application! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `JPanel` with a `BoxLayout`:

```
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
panel.add(new JLabel("one"));
panel.add(new JLabel("zwei"));
panel.add(new JLabel("trois"));
panel.add(new JLabel("vier"));
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

If you are using "pixel hungry" scroll panes, the layout manager will give them more room if it is available (the scroll panes want as much space as possible). You can change that by limiting the maximum height of the scroll panes, for example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SearchPanel2 {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new SearchPanel2().launchGui();
    }

    private void launchGui() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow: box layout & scroll panes");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        final Dimension maximumSize = new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 80);
        addLabel(panel, "one", maximumSize);
        addLabel(panel, "zwei", maximumSize);
        addLabel(panel, "trois", maximumSize);
        addLabel(panel, "vier", maximumSize);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addLabel(JPanel panel, String word, Dimension maximumSize) {
        String text = ".......... " + word;
        for (int blahIndex = 0; blahIndex < 28; blahIndex++)
            text += " ..........";
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(text));
        scrollPane.setMaximumSize(maximumSize);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
    }
}
```

Comment: Been playing with that but box layout does not seam to fill the full width of the panel.

Comment: It should use all space. Are you sure that the panel is as wide as you expect? It could be caused by the layout manager of the component that you add the panel to (in this case the frame). Add (some of) your code to your question to make sure we are looking at the same issue.

Comment: Ok, the box layout is working after reading a lot or references on how to use it.  Thanks

Comment: Good to hear you've got it working. I've added an example with box layout and scroll panes which might be useful for your project.